# Is it possible to detect left swipe multi-touch with "two fingers" on Xamarin.Forms especially on UWP? [iOS, Android, UWP]

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I want to detect left swipe with multi-touch within AbsoluteLayout. Is it possible to detect multi-touch with "two fingers" on Xamarin.Forms?

Here is SwipeGesture sample from Xamarin but its only detect direction of the swipe. (https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WorkingWithGestures/SwipeGesture/)

Comment: check out https://www.mrgestures.com/

Comment: Already know MR.Gestures but it's not free.

Comment: well that is the only thing available